# Avoid expansion of certain TreeNode nodes upon TreeNode.ExpandAll?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, treeview, treenode

Nobody asked that before:

What is an efficient way to avoid the expansion of certain `TreeNode` class descendants in a WinForms `TreeView` when the user does the "Expand all" thing, but still let him expand such nodes by clicking on the + symbol?

Sure I can handle `BeforeExpand`, but I have a hard time setting `e.Cancel` to `true` only if it is an `ExpandAll` operation. I wonder how I can determine this? I could subclass `TreeView` and override `ExpandAll` -- but that one cannot be overriden...

Comment: Simple question, no replies? Probably not as trivial as I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works 100%. I think. Sigh.

```
  Private Sub MyTreeViewExpandNodes(ByVal Nodes As TreeNodeCollection)
    For Each Node As TreeNode In Nodes
      If Not (TypeOf Node Is SpecialTreeNode) Then
        Node.Expand()
        MyTreeViewExpandNodes(Node.Nodes)
      End If
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub MyTreeView_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyTreeView.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Multiply Then
      e.Handled = True
      e.SuppressKeyPress = True
      MyTreeViewExpandNodes(MyTreeView.Nodes)
    End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like standard .NET treeview doesn`t have the way other than you described: trigger flag before ExpandAll, handle BeforeExpand and enable e.Cancel for appropriate nodes when flag is enabled.

As the ExpandAll method isn`t virtual you have these ways to follow:

- Inherit from the TreeView class and add ExpandAllEx method where trigger this flag. No a good one because you need to cast to your tree class everywhere you use the tree instance.
- Add an extension method for the TreeView class where use tree.Tag property for this flag. More useful way with minimal changes in existing code.

Comment: I got the general idea behind both options, however I do not understand how to implement either of them exactly. What would the extension method do? How would I make sure it is triggered if the user pushed the asterisk on the numeric pad? Similarily, how would I make sure ExpandAllEx in my TreeView descendant will be triggered instead of ExpandAll if the user pushes the asterisk?

Comment: +1 for the dedication of the account, according to the name :)